# SQLAlchemy Foreign key constraint confusion

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I just want to delete a survey record in the `Survey` table, and the record in `SurveyQuestions` should be deleted too. I've tried `cascade`, `passive_deletes`, and `ondelete`. I keep getting the foreign key violation error no matter what I try from the documentation. Is it the way my tables are set up?

```
class Survey(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'survey'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    survey_description = Column(String(100))
    survey_start_date = Column(Date)
    survey_end_date = Column(Date)
    survey_is_active = Column(Boolean)
    survey_questions = relationship(Question, secondary='survey_questions',cascade="all, delete",passive_deletes=True)


class SurveyQuestions(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'survey_questions'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    survey_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('survey.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    question_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('question.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

Comment: [association](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) might be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to drop all the tables using `Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)` before the foreign key relations would take effect. Since then we have adopted [alembic](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/) to remedy this issue through the use of migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Are there other models that use `Survey` as a foreign key?
Perhaps the foreign key violation happens because you didn't specify `ondelete` strategy in another model that points to `Survey`